# Optimizing Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I decided to build a little Tic-Tac-Toe game, I'm storing the X's and O's in an array and have a function to check the array to see if anyone has won.

Right now I'm just doing a big giant IF

```
if ((board[0] == valueToCheck && board[1] == valueToCheck && board[2] == valueToCheck) ||
    (board[3] == valueToCheck && board[4] == valueToCheck && board[5] == valueToCheck) ||
    (board[6] == valueToCheck && board[7] == valueToCheck && board[8] == valueToCheck) ||
    (board[0] == valueToCheck && board[3] == valueToCheck && board[6] == valueToCheck) ||
    (board[1] == valueToCheck && board[4] == valueToCheck && board[7] == valueToCheck) ||
    (board[2] == valueToCheck && board[5] == valueToCheck && board[8] == valueToCheck) ||
    (board[0] == valueToCheck && board[4] == valueToCheck && board[8] == valueToCheck) ||
    (board[2] == valueToCheck && board[4] == valueToCheck && board[6] == valueToCheck)) {
```

I'm just wondering if there's a more optimized way to do this as I'm about to build a computerized opponent and it should check to see if it's opponent is about to win, oh and I'm not using jQuery

Comment: [This might give you an idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)

Comment: When you say optimized, do you mean to run faster, or to use less code?

Comment: "Optimized" means fewer cpu cycles. "Obfuscated" is less code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it by using an array to store the possible combinations :

```
var combinations = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
];

var win = false;
for(var i = 0 ; i < combinations.length ; i++) {
    var c = combinations[i];
    if(board[c[0]] == valueToCheck && board[c[1]] == valueToCheck && board[c[2]] == valueToCheck) {
        win = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(win) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How is this any more efficient than the code in the OP? It's the exact same comparisons, except this answer has the additional overhead of a loop. This is LESS efficient than the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would serialize the board somehow, (for instance as a string of spaces, X's and O's) and then simply compare the current string to a known ending game string.

```
 | |
-+-+-
X| |
-+-+-
 | |O
```

Becomes

```
var gameState = "   X    O";
```

Comment: There are a lot of possible winning states, but this is an interesting idea.

Comment: I don't see any benefit to this. If you implement the comparison with a basic string compare, you require a giant list of all possible ending configurations. If you implement the comparison with a more sophisticated method, you could do it as easily without the serialization.

Comment: I was going for easy to implement, and an incremental step up from where the poster is now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short way using Array's `some` and `every`. Not [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Browser_compatibility) with old browsers.

```
var wins = [
   [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], // rows
   [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], // columns
   [0,4,8], [2,4,6] ];        // diagonals

var is_value = function(i) { return board[i] == valueToCheck; };

if( wins.some(function(a){return a.every(is_value);}) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Represent each square as two bits in an 18-bit number:

00=blank,
10="O",
11="X"

and the squares are in the following order:

```
1|2|3
-+-+-
4|5|6
-+-+-
7|8|9
```

so that X's in the top row (with all other squares empty) is represented by the integer 258048 (which in binary is 111111000000000000).

Now, if you're wanting to see if X has won, you use bitwise AND (&) against the 8 possible winning combinations:

```
if (
    (gameBoard & 258048 === 258048) ||   // top row full of X's
    (gameBoard & 4032 === 4032)     ||   // middle row full of X's
    // etc.
   ) { // X has won }
```

Ideally, you put each winning combo (again, there are only 8) in an array and run through them like so:

```
if (
    (gameBoard & winningXCombo[0] === winningXCombo[0]) ||   // top row full of X's
    (gameBoard & winningXCombo[1] === winningXCombo[1]) ||   // middle row full of X's
    // etc.
   ) { // X has won }
```

And, if you truly want to optimize, check for the 4 winning combos that go through the center square first. In a game against an intelligent opponent, the winner will most likely have the center square. Checking those combos first will let you take advantage of short-circuiting in evaluation of the conditional.